# Integracion Jenkins-Maven java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'when' found among steps

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Tengo un pipeline en jenkins con maven 3.0.2, que quiero actualizar la version del sonarqube de la 6.7 a la 8.9.Al intentar usar la condicion "when" en Jenkins (primera vez q lo intento), me da error No such DSL method 'when' found among steps. Segun lei es q falta algun plugin de maven, ya intente algunos pero sigue sin funcionar. Alguna idea?

```
container ("standard") {
try {
stage('mySq') {
                    when { not  {changeRequest()}  }
                    steps {
                     withSonarQubeEnv(installationName: 'mySqinst', credentialsId: 'myCred') 
                     {  withMaven(maven: env.MAVEN_VERSION, jdk: 'OpenJDK-Latest-JDK11', 
                        globalMavenSettingsConfig: env.MAVEN_GLOBAL_CONFIG) {
                        //s
                        sh '''
                            mvn -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN} \
                                -Dsonar.branch.name=${BRANCH_NAME} \
                                ${SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL}
                           '''
                        }
                      }
                    }
}catch {exception e}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Hm, no, la sintaxis del pipeline es de Jenkins, ahí no estás haciendo nada con maven (hasta que haces sh mvn...).  Habría que ver si tu pipeline es [declarativo](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) (que debe serlo para usar when) o scripted. Por favor, ve a [edit] la pregunta y muéstranos un fragmento más grande del script para ver de qué tipo es.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias ! creo q has dado en el clavo, segun tu documentacion el declarativo empieza con "pipeline" . Asi que el mio asumo que es scripted y por eso no funcionaba..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En efecto, tu pipeline tiene definición *scripted* (la viejita) y ahí no existe `when`.

Tienes que migrarlo para que sea declarativo. Revisa [este enlace](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#scripted-pipeline-fundamentals) para que veas la diferencia. Un ejemplo básico es:

```
pipeline { 
    agent any 
    options {
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps { 
                sh 'make' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test'){
            steps {
                sh 'make check'
                junit 'reports/**/*.xml' 
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh 'make publish'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si usas un container docker, es necesario que revises cómo se ejecuta un contenedor y usarlo como agent. Luego, va un conjunto de `stages`, cada uno con un conjunto de `steps`.

Puedes revisar tu versión de Jenkins y ver si, dentro del job, tienes la opción pipeline syntax que te ayuda a armar pasos con la sintaxis correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias! muy util la info. Tambien, para quien lea esta pregunta, en Jenkins hay una forma de generar el pipeline declarativo dentro del job.
[image: Pipeline Declarativo]